# Quotationmarks in html

Tags: html, tags, quotation-marks

Today i read:

> Don’t use single quotation marks around paths for images. When setting
>   a background image, resist the urge to surround the path with quote
>   marks. They’re not necessary, and IE5/Mac will choke.

Meaning instead of:

```
<img src="pic_mountain.jpg" title="Mountain-View" style="width:304px;height:228px;">
```

this:

```
<img src=pic_mountain.jpg title=Mountain-View style=width:304px;height:228px;>
```

should be perfectly fine. Is this true? No diffrences? It does work normally on my end. Is it about cross-browser compatibility?
Source for the info: [Source](http://www.mezzoblue.com/css/cribsheet/)

Comment: Yes, quote-less attributes are officially supported syntax. Read [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attributes). Whether you should still care about IE5/Mac is extremely debatable…

Answer (score 3):

The quote is talking about CSS, not HTML.

These all mean the same in CSS:

```
background-image: url(/path/to/foo);
background-image: url("/path/to/foo");
background-image: url('/path/to/foo');
```

… except only the first one works in IE5/Mac … which hasn't been supported for a very long time, so isn't worth worrying about.

---

The two versions of HTML in your question are (for reasons unrelated to the quote you included) also equivalent.

The common view about best practise is that you *should* always place quotes around HTML attribute values. It saves having to remember which characters that you might want to place in an attribute value turn the quote from optional into required. Space is an obvious example of such a character.

Answer (score 0):

It is valid html but if you then use an attribute that is not valid for an element it will then through an error this link should help.

[unquoted attributes](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/unquoted-attribute-values)

Comment: *"but if you then use an attribute that is not valid for an element it will then through an error"* – Wut?!